# omega-alpha limit set and manifold

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, chaos-theory

> Definition:
>
> The $\omega$-limit set $L_{\omega}\left ( x \right )$ of $x \in \mathbb{M}$ >is the set of $y \in \mathbb{M}$ which for each y there exists a
> strictly increasing unbounded sequence of times
>
> $t_{0}<t_{1}<t_{2}<\cdot \cdot \cdot $
>
> such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left \| \Psi_{t_{n}}\left ( x \right )-y \right \|=0$
>
> Definition:
>
> Let $S\subseteq \mathbb{M}$ be an invariant set.
>
> $W^{s}_{s}\left ( S \right )=\left \{ y \in\mathbb{M}:L_{\omega}\left ( y \right )\subseteq S \right \}$
>
> -inset, stable set, stable manifold

and

> $W^{u}\left ( S \right )=\left \{ y \in \mathbb{M}:L_{\alpha}\left ( y \right )\subseteq S \right \}$
>
> -outset, unstable set, unstable manifold

I would like to request for a more contextual explanation of the above definition. Would someone kindly do so? Geometrical intuition would be even helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an unusual way of describing stable/unstable manifolds, and actually wrong in general.

How about say $x'=-x^2$ that has no stable manifold but that according to this definition has? Simply it is not standard (nor correct).

On the other hand, the intuition is clear: stable manifolds of $S$ should more or less be (although in general are not) the set of points that converge to the set $S$.

Comment: What is the proper definition? These definitions came from my note.

Comment: The theory is huge and the notion of stable manifold is central in the stability theory, so it is impossible to give details. What do you mean by "my note"?

Comment: My lecture notes I meant.